# Div display none/hidden javascript function in asp.net

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on a blog. Now I want a button and if a user clicks on the button it wil show the comments under the blogs. I have written a javascript function for it but for some reason it doesn't work. I can see in the web inspector that the element gets set to display block but it stil doesn't get visible.

**This is my view**

```
@model IEnumerable<Portfolio.Models.Messages>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/Comments.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/Blog.css" />

@foreach (var messages in Model)
{
    <div class="jumbotron opacity_container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2 class="panel-title">
                        @messages.Title</h2>@messages.WhenCreated
                </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                 @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(messages.Body))
                    </div>
              </div>
         </div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="@messages.MessagesId" 
onclick="ShowComments(this.id)">
Show Comments
</button>

    <div class="hidden" id="Comm@(messages.MessagesId)">
        @Html.Partial("_Comment")
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="@messages.MessagesId" 
        onclick="HideComments(this.id)">
        Hide Comments</button>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

> The div with the hidden class is the class that i want to turn visible

**this is the partial view**

```
@model IEnumerable<Portfolio.Models.Messages>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/css/Blog.css" />

<div class="row" id="CommentContainer">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h2>Comments</h2>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="CommentButton1">
            Place Comment
        </button>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-10">
               @foreach(var messages in Model)
                {
                <div class="well" id="CommentBox">                       
                 @Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(messages.Body))
                </div>
                }
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is the css**

```
body {
background-image: url('../images/blogbckgrnd.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center top;
}

.jumbotron.opacity_container {
    background-color: rgba(51, 53, 56, 0.6);
}

col-md-12.message {
    font-size: 0.5vw;
}

#MessageContainer {
    margin: 0vw;
}

#CommentButton{
margin: 0.4vh 0vw 1.5vh 1vw;
}

#CommentButton1 {
margin: 0.4vh 0vw 1.5vh 1vw;
}

#CommentBox {
background-color: gray;
}

.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

> The hidden class sets the div to display none

**This is The Javascript function**

```
function ShowComments(getId)
{
    var Id = "Comm" + getId;
    var CommId = document.getElementById(Id);
    CommId.style.display = "block";
}
```

> This function gets called with a onclick event from the button

I am pretty new on stack overflow so if things can be told better please tell me!

Comment: Can your show method just remove the "hidden" class?

Comment: I could try thnx for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion I have tried Hopeless solution and it worked. here the answer:

**The new javascript function**

```
    function ShowComments(getId)
    {
        var Id = "Comm" + getId;
        var CommId = document.getElementById(Id).className = "show";
    }
```

what i do here is switching between two classnames to hide or show the comments

Comment: Anything that removes the 'hidden' class would work, I guess.  You could dispense with all the IDs by just using `var CommId = this.nextSibling;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use div with css in your html page and javascript onchange function for your dropdownlist... No need to reload anything

Css:

```
    .on {
    display: block;
    }
    .off {
    display: none;
    }
```

the script will look like that or close...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            document.getElementById('DIV1').className = 'off';
            document.getElementById('DIV2').className = 'off';
        });      
    $('#DDL').on('change', function() {
       if ( this.value == '1')
       {
                document.getElementById('INF1').className = 'on';
                document.getElementById('INF2').className = 'off';
       }
       else if ( this.value == '2')
       {
                document.getElementById('INF1').className = 'off';
                document.getElementById('INF2').className = 'on';
       }
    etc.
   });
});
```

And for the html just put the ids according to your script